# For each element x in a list, check if other elements are in range(x-2, x+2)

Tags: python, list, loops, range

For each element of a python list, I want to check if others are in a given range corresponding to that element and then return those elements with their indices.

For example:

```
list = [9, 10, 15, 20, 21, 22]
range = (x-2 to x+2)
```

Result:

```
9  - range: 7-11, element:10, index:1
10 - range: 8-12, element:9, index:0
15 - range: 13-17, element:, index:
20 - range: 18-22, element:21,22, index:4,5
21 - range: 19-23, element:20,22, index:3,5
22 - range: 20-24, element:20,21, index:3,4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension, using `enumerate` to get indexes of each element and comparing all the other values with the current value `+/-2`:

```py
l = [9, 10, 15, 20, 21, 22]

result = [[(v, i) for i, v in enumerate(l) if abs(v-x) < 3 and i != j] for j, x in enumerate(l)]
```

Output:

```py
[
 [(10, 1)],
 [(9, 0)],
 [],
 [(21, 4), (22, 5)],
 [(20, 3), (22, 5)],
 [(20, 3), (21, 4)]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your list is sorted you can make this more efficient, but you can use this as a starting point.

```py
list = [9, 10, 15, 20, 21, 22]

for a in list:
    in_range = []
    indices = []
    for i, b in enumerate(list):
        if b == a:
            continue

        if a - 2 <= b <= a + 2:
            in_range.append(b)
            indices.append(i)

    print(f'{a} - range: {a - 2}-{a + 2}, element:{in_range}, index:{indices}')
```